# Cannot convert 'const char*' to 'WCHAR*' in argument passing

Tags: c++, char, wchar

I have documentation where written that username, IP and password must be `const char*` and when I'm putting varaibles in `const char`, I'm getting this error message.

This is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
    MYPROC ProcAdd;   
    hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("LmServerAPI.dll");
    if(hinstDLL != NULL){
        ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL,"LmServer_Login");            
        if(ProcAdd != NULL){
            const char* IP = "xxx.177.xxx.23";
            const char* name = "username";
            const char* pass = "password";
            int port = 888;
            ProcAdd(IP,port,name,pass);
            system ("pause");          
        }          
    }
}
```

And I got this error:

> cannot convert `const char*' to`WCHAR*' in argument passing

Which kind of variable must I use for those arguments and how?

Comment: A `LPWSTR` aka `wchar_t *`?

Comment: i'm new in c++, cannot convert const char*' toWCHAR*' in argument passing this is error from dev++

Comment: Is there some reason `ProcAdd` takes a `LPWSTR` if you're mandating (per your question) a `const char*`, where neither the const-ness not the character width match?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are most likely using one of the Visual Studio compilers, where in `Project Settings`, there is a `Character set` choice. Choose from:

- Unicode character set (UTF-16), default
- Multi-Byte character set (UTF-8)
- Not Set

Calling functions that accept strings in the Unicode setting requires you to make Unicode string literals:

```cpp
"hello"
```

Is of type `const char*`, whereas:

```cpp
L"hello"
```

is of type `const wchar_t*`. So either change your configuration to `Not set` or change your string literals to wide ones.

Comment: i'm using dev C++ compiler what i must change in this compiler?

Comment: That's a pretty unknown compiler to me. There could be a similar setting somewhere. If you can't find it, just make the literals Unicode (at lines where the errors you describe occur).

Comment: Also, your `MYPROC` is flawed, it has one non-`const` argument but you are passing four const ones (port, ip, user and password). But that bug is unrelated to your question. Correct would be `typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPCWSTR, int, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR)`. But you best refer to the page where the interface of `LmServerAPI.dll` is described, as using a different interface will result in crash or undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: I just explained in my answer. Non-Unicode: `const char *text = "hello";` Unicode: `const wchar_t *text = L"hello";`. That goes also for the arguments to `LoadLibrary` or `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: It would also probably help to say on which lines the error(s) are reported.

Comment: thanks bro i love you soo much, problem was typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPCWSTR, int, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR) that line it works now, thanks thanks thanks ^_^

Comment: If only UTF-8 was that well-supported by MS.

Comment: For those looking for this in Visual Studio 2017, it's under Project Properties > Configuration > General tab > Project Defaults > Character Set.

Answer (score 3):

For literals, you want to use `L` on the string as in:

```
L"My String"
```

If you may compile in wide character or not, then you may want to consider using the `_T()` macro instead:

```
_T("My String")
```

Wide string characters under MS-Windows make use of the UTF-16 format. For more information about Unicode formats, look on the [Unicode website](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

To dynamically convert a string, you need to know the format of your `char *` string. In most cases, under Windows it is a Win1252, but definitively not always. Microsoft Windows supports many 8 bit formats, including UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.

If you trust the locale setup, you could use the [`mbstowc_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx.aspx) functions.

For other conversions, you may want to look at the [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function