# emplace_back different definitions

Tags: c++, mfc, string-conversion, c2664

I'm using `emplace_back` function in a cpp project in visual studio and it works correctly. Visual studio shows following definition for it:

```
void std::vector<std::string>::emplace_back<CHAR(&)[1]>(CHAR(&_Val)[1])
```

Then, I'm going to move my cpp project files to a MFC project and use them in a dialog based app. When I moved codes to MFC project, `emplace_back` definition has changed to:

```
void std::vector<std::string>::emplace_back<WCHAR(&)[1]>(WCHAR(&_Val)[1])
```

And it leads to `C2664` Error in xmemory0 after build:

```
Error   C2664
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> &)':
cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [1]' to 'std::initializer_list<_Elem>'
```

And in output it says:

```
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>::emplace_back<WCHAR(&)[1]>(WCHAR (&)[1])' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
```

How can I deal with such problems? Is there any option in properties of Visual Studio Project to correct?

Thanks

Comment: It's about 'Character set', https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073905/853569

Comment: How you're using it is very relevant to the question. The error looks like the instantiation you used changed, not the definition.

Comment: There is a vector of strings and you are trying to add a single wide char to this vector? Explain what you are trying to accomplish and what code you are using. Also have a look at `std::wstring` for Unicode string, or `vector<wstring>` for vector of Unicode strings.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code where you call `std::vector<std::string>::emplace_back()` that is causing the problem. I suppose the argument for `emplace_back()` is `TCHAR` based. In the project where it worked you propably build for ANSI character set (`TCHAR` is typedef for `char`), in the new project you propably have Unicode enabled (`TCHAR` is typedef for `wchar_t`).